# How to make Sound Alert in Lua?

Tags: audio, lua

I want to write a function

whenever I call  it must be make a sound alert 
is it possible in Lua ?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but not without work; There's no such function in the lua standard library.

Are you sure you need this? There are few things more annoying than beeping programs.

Comment: How about `print '\a'`  ?

Answer (score 2):

This should be your solution:

```
os.execute("echo \7")
```

or

```
os.execute("echo \a")
```

This creates a short beep (using the speaker, not the beeper).

** Tested on Windows. But should work in UNIX also.

Comment: I could not execute it on SciTE or Eclipse Lua, I am taking the following error: "'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."    how did you run it ?

Comment: I get the same error, that is normal - but the beep comes anyway.

You can look here:
http://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt
I use only Notepad++ and Windows CMD.. No special thing like Eclipse or SciTE, i dont like them. It can be that your System does not accept the beep. Look the link above.

Comment: os.execute("echo \7") is better than os.execute("\7"). I edited it. Now you wont get the error message, but the beep will stay.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. No error reported. Windows 10.